# Insert new term during new post creation

Tags: wp-insert-post, terms

i am currently working on a snippet to insert a new post dynamically (it's a custom post type). During this new post creation i need to insert terms in custom taxonomies associated to the custom post type.

I am having the famous "invalid taxonomy" error message and i don't know how to solve this.

Here is the code i'm using:

- the custom post type is: property
- the custom taxonomy is: type

Code:

```
// Insert property into DB
$property = array(
    'post_title'   => $title,
    'post_content' => $description,
    'post_status'  => 'draft',
    'post_author'  => 1,
    'post_type'    => 'property'
);

// Insert the post into the database
$property_id = wp_insert_post( $property );         

// Taxo Property Type
if( $property_type ) {

    // check if term exists
    $property_type_term = term_exists( $property_type, 'type' );

    if( $property_type_term !== 0 && $term !== null ) {
        // Term exists, get the term id
        $property_type_term_id = $property_type_term;
    } else {
        // Create new term
        $property_type_term_id = wp_insert_term(
                                    $property_type,     // the term 
                                    'type'          // the taxonomy
                                );
    }

    // Assign term id to post
    wp_set_post_terms( $property_id, array($property_type_term_id), 'type' );

}
```

With this code, the post is correctly created but the term not.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You're likely calling  wp_set_post_terms prior to your taxonomy being registered.

Comment: i'm using this code in a shortcode (inside a plugin), and the taxonomy is registered previously in the plugin.

Comment: what is the `$property_type` refer to?

Comment: $property_type is just a $_POST[] var not empty. In fact, the code works, i just saw that the bug was in the taxonomy registration, in other words: how to lose time for nothing ! Thanks by the way to those who answered me !

Comment: first you should set the taxnomy in custom post type you have just set only for post title post content post comments you did not set for custom taxnomy 'tax_input'      => [ array( <taxonomy> => <array | string> ) ] // For custom taxonomies. Default empty.
  'page_template'  => [ <string> ] // Requires name of template file, eg template.php. Default empty.
);

Answer (score 1):

first you should set the taxnomy in custom post type you have just set only for post title post content post comments you did not set for custom taxnomy

```
$post = array('tax_input'      => [ array( <taxonomy> => <array | string> ) ] // For custom taxonomies. Default empty.
  'page_template'  => [ <string> ] // Requires name of template file, eg template.php. Default empty.
);
```

this query will set the custom taxnomy while creating custom post [check this link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post)